# windows 10 (modern) Universal app Platform (UWP) messagebox

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app

how can i make a messagebox on windows 10 (modern) Universal app Platform (UWP) like on windows clasic form(messagebox.show)?
thanks

Answer (score 4):

For Universal Apps, the new APIs require you to use await

```
MessageDialog().ShowAsync() (in Windows.UI.Popups) 
// to bring it into line with Win 8.1.

var dialog = new MessageDialog("Your message here Hello");
await dialog.ShowAsync();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
var dialog = new MessageDialog("Your message here");
await dialog.ShowAsync();
```

Comment: it's works with windwos 10 last SDK?

Comment: yes, it does..just add: using Windows.UI.Popups;

Answer (score 1):

```
var dialog = new MessageDialog("Hello World");
await dialog.ShowAsync();
```

Comment: and how can i set the title or more data on the dialog?

Comment: There is a title property you can set https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.popups.messagedialog.title

Comment: what device type are you targeting?